# Save data from multiple jtextfields and combo boxes to .TXT file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I've been trying for a few weeks to get this program working, without success. Its a simple program created in SwingUI with multiple text fields and combo boxes. I want to save data inputted into those fields to a text file. I'm able to get the data from the FName field, but nothing else. Perhaps someone here can lead me in the right direction?

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Thank you for joining BPA! Your information has been submitted.");
    String content = FName.getText();
                     LName.getText();//step1: get the content of the textfield

try {

            File file = new File("c:/users/User/Documents/BPASignup.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);    //step2: write it
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how to concatenate strings? Like this:

```
String content = "First name: " + FName.getText() + "\n" +
                 "Last name: " + LName.getText() + "\n\n";
```

I suppose there is no point explaining how and why to use `StringBuilder` at this point.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working. How would I add a blank line in between each string in the text file?

Comment: `\n` is the newline character. Just add more of them if you need.

Comment: So it was already supposed to add a new line with the code you showed me? Its not working. Everything is still on one line when I open the text document.

Comment: It depends on the text editor you open it with. Microsoft's Notepad only supports `\r\n` combination for newlines, but any decent text editor should show `\n` just fine.

Comment: I was using notepad. I got it working. Thank you so much for your help! I've been trying to get it working for almost a month with no luck.

Comment: One more question. How would I save comboboxes instead of JTextFields?

Comment: `JComboBox#getSelectedItem()` gives you the selected value. See http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JComboBoxgetSelectedItem.htm

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I tried the code, and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

when initializing the string content you used this code:

```
 String content = FName.getText();
                  LName.getText();
```

this will only work if you use:

```
String content = FName.getText() + LName.getText();
```

i've made a little program that does what you request with swing for myself too:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Write{
    static JButton button;
    static JTextField one;
    static JTextField two;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        one = new JTextField(20);
        two = new JTextField(20);
        button = new JButton("write file");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(one);
        mainPanel.add(two);
        mainPanel.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try{
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String content = one.getText() + " " + two.getText();
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
            } catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

maybe this can help too.